# Grouping in R by any combination

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations

Ok so I have a dataset that looks like:

```
player1 player2 player3 player4 player5  time
     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <dbl>
 1  201566 1628390  203500  203924  202331  693.
 2  201571  203095  202696  203932 1628371  692.
 3  203081  203468  203994  202329  203090  526.
 4  202339 1627763  201572  203507  203114  504.
 5  201937 1628378  203497  202324  204060  476.
 6  201954  203506 1626167  201152  202711  409.
 7  202689  203087  203469  101107  201587  404.
 8  200768  201980  201586 1627783  202695  391.
 9 1628368 1627741 1626161  202357  202697  387.
10  201144  202066  201188 1628991  203937  373.
```

And it extends like this with different combinations. My problem currently is that any number can show up in any column, and what I want is to group by the most common group of 5 based on the time, but

```
group_by(player1, player2, player3, player4, player5)
```

won't work because I want any combination of the five.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: is it based on column names

Comment: Can you make what *"based on the time"*  means? Do you want the most common combination of 5 numbers *and* time?

Comment: @RuiBarradas No, I want the total time based on the combinations. Essentially adding the time up of the same combos

Comment: @akrun Im not sure what you mean, but any number (which corresponds to a player), could appear in any column. I'm looking for the total time of the most common combos which could be in any column, as it could be the same players but in different orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
First create a vector of players' numbers, sorted and pasted together. Then use this vector as aggregation variable. Any of `tapply` or `aggregate` can compute the sums of `time` by group of `inx`.

```
inx <- apply(df1[-6], 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "."))
tapply(df1$time, inx, sum)
aggregate(time ~ inx, df1, sum)
```

Comment: This worked, it just mushed all the playerids together with periods separating into one column, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a longer tidyverse approach where we go long, sort into consistent order, go wide, and do the original counting:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data %>%
  pivot_longer(-time) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0("player", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  
  count(player1, player2, player3, player4, player5)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   player1 player2 player3 player4 player5     n
     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int>
 1  101107  201587  202689  203087  203469     1
 2  200768  201586  201980  202695 1627783     1
 3  201144  201188  202066  203937 1628991     1
 4  201152  201954  202711  203506 1626167     1
 5  201566  202331  203500  203924 1628390     1
 6  201571  202696  203095  203932 1628371     1
 7  201572  202339  203114  203507 1627763     1
 8  201937  202324  203497  204060 1628378     1
 9  202329  203081  203090  203468  203994     1
10  202357  202697 1626161 1627741 1628368     1
```

input data in loadable format:

```
my_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~player1, ~player2, ~player3, ~player4, ~player5, ~time,
   201566L, 1628390L,  203500L,  203924L,  202331L,  693,
   201571L,  203095L,  202696L,  203932L, 1628371L,  692,
   203081L,  203468L,  203994L,  202329L,  203090L,  526,
   202339L, 1627763L,  201572L,  203507L,  203114L,  504,
   201937L, 1628378L,  203497L,  202324L,  204060L,  476,
   201954L,  203506L, 1626167L,  201152L,  202711L,  409,
   202689L,  203087L,  203469L,  101107L,  201587L,  404,
   200768L,  201980L,  201586L, 1627783L,  202695L,  391,
  1628368L, 1627741L, 1626161L,  202357L,  202697L,  387,
   201144L,  202066L,  201188L, 1628991L,  203937L,  373
  )
```